# How to extract articles from Hindi Web pages with Goose?

Tags: goose

I'm using Python Goose to extract articles from Web pages. It works fine for many languages, but fails for Hindi. I have tried to add Hindi stop as stopwords-hi.txt and set target_language to hi, without success.
Thanks, Eran

Comment: What exactly fails how?

Comment: The cleaned_text function returns nothing

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I had the same problem. I've been working on extracting articles in all Indian regional languages and I couldn't extract the content alone with Goose.
If you can work with the article description alone, the meta_description works perfectly. You can use that instead of cleaned_text which doesn't return anything.

Another alternative, but more lines of code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.jagran.com/news/national-this-pay-scale-calculator-will-tell-your-new-salary-after-7th-pay-commission-14132357.html"
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

##removing all script, style and reference links to get only the article content
for script in soup(["script", "style",'a',"href","formfield"]):
    script.extract()  


text = soup.get_text()

lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

print (text)
```

Open disclosure: I actually got the original code somewhere on stack overflow only. Modified it a tiny bit.